# Does minifying your custom .js files have a benefit in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, performance, dynamics-crm-2011

We are using microsoft CRM 2011.  I have a developer who wants to minify our custom .js files (maybe 2 or 3 of them per form) because he believes it will improve performance.

I agree that in a web site with thousands of hits, many of whom don't have your javascript cached, minifying is helpful.  However, in CRM, we have pretty much a set number of users, most if not all of whom already have the .js files cached.  And, CRM has hundreds of it's own .js files, our few custom files are a small percentage.

Can anyone comment on best practices as far as Micrsoft dynamics CRM and minification of custom javascript code?

Comment: loading X bytes instead of Y bytes (where X < Y) will improve performance. The loading time will be reduced by 0,00000[put your number here] seconds, considering that JS inside CRM are often of few KB. Probably your developer is the type that loves to debug minified javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a performance improvement but it is highly unlikely to have any material impact on your server load or user experience.

Unless you have a performance issue to solve and have implemented an automated build process that handles the minification I would avoid minifying the JS files. You are going to create additional development and troubleshooting complexity without any material benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You should always minify your javascript to improve performance.

There is a reference !!

http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/extending-crm/javascript/crm-javascript-best-practices/